# Angular version among listed versions by command ng -v

Tags: angular

What would be the Angular version I'm using? I could see many versions being listed by `ng -v command` (image posted). Please could you help me?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You are using Angular 4.4.6 version.

You can see it at the line `@angular/core` displayed by `ng -g` or in your `package.json` file.